# Xcode 11 beta crashes when starting in Virtual machine

Tags: crash, vmware, beta, xcode11

i have just downloaded Xcode 11 beta and installed in a vm environment. When trying to start a new playground or project, xcode quits with following error code. Any idea how to solve ?

```
Process:               Xcode [426]  
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode  
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode  
Version:               11.0 (14855.18)  
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-14855018000000000~13  
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)  
Parent Process:        ??? [1]  
Responsible:           Xcode [426]  
User ID:               501  


Date/Time:             2019-06-08 08:13:37.785 -0700  
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F132)  
Report Version:        12  
Anonymous UUID:        CB32DBDA-4F6E-4212-F810-C52C80FFD0CD
```

Link to full error: 
https://pastebin.com/fFhcadtZ

Comment: I have got comparable experiences (in a VM). Did you test this with a cocoapods project?

Comment: same issue with a cocoapods project :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fixed in XCode 11 beta 2, available on developer.apple.com !!!

June 17 2019.

1. You don't need MacOS Catalina, only Mojave 10.14.4 and up (current is 10.14.5).
2. I used VMware on Windows to install Mojave and XCode beta 2.

Comment: It works but in Mojave the SwiftUi canvas is not loading. Will try if it works on Catalina ...or is it that metal is unavailable ? Will try in a moment

Comment: Confirmed that Xcode 11 Beta 2 works in my Parallels VM, thanks for the tip! SwiftUI for macOS apps still requires Catalina (iOS et al use simulators, so they work fine in Mojave).

Comment: Correct. Updated to Catalina and SwiftUI + canvas now works !! Hooray

Comment: Confirmed that Xcode 11 Beta 2 works OK in Virtualbox, even when the host has a non-metal GPU.

Answer (score 4):

This should probably be a comment, not an answer, but I lack the reputation to do so. [Here](https://twitter.com/LouisDhauwe/status/1136453158769528832) is the xcode developer who developed the minimap indicating that while the minimap indeed does require metal, xcode should not crash when metal is not available. Hopefully he implements a patch to fail gracefully in one of the next builds. As of right now, there is no workaround. The reply to the thread:

```
defaults write http://com.apple .dt.Xcode DVTTextShowMinimap -bool NO
```

does not prevent the crash, as mentioned there.

Comment: alright, thanks for pointing this out. Please let me know if you find a way around it !

Comment: I will update my post if I hear anything or find a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I attempted the same with Parallels (with tools installed), and also observed a crash. I suspect the problem is with the virtualization software lacking support for Metal. Notice the stack trace on the main thread:

> 0   com.apple.dt.SourceEditor         0x0000000120ccb5cb specialized
>   static MinimapMetalLinesLayer.defaultDevice() + 491 1
>   com.apple.dt.SourceEditor         0x0000000120cc959c
>   MinimapMetalLinesLayer.init() + 284

The "Minimap" is a new feature in Xcode 11, it's a birds eye view of the source code in a column on the right (similar to Sublime text edit). Also notice the mention of [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/), Apple's graphics API. To test this theory, I opened Xcode 10 (in the same VM) and attempted to build one of Apple's examples. I got the following error, which seems to confirm my suspicion that Parallels is unable to support apps using Metal.

> 2019-06-09 09:15:17.875253-0400 HelloTriangle[652:7547] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[AAPLViewController viewDidLoad],
>   /Users/ZestyMeta/Downloads/UsingARenderPipelineToRenderPrimitives/Application/AAPLViewController.m:27
>   2019-06-09 09:15:17.875403-0400 HelloTriangle[652:7547] Failed to set
>   (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow):
>   Metal is not supported on this device

I haven't attempted installing macOS Catalina / Xcode 11 in VirtualBox, VMWare, et al. but unless they support Metal then this crash will happen there as well. If you're testing out Catalina (which is required for SwiftUI on macOS), unfortunately it seems the solution at this time is to install on a spare device or [dual boot](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/dual-boot-mac-3659676/).

Comment: On machines with T2 chips, dual booting seems like a truly awful plan. The Bridge OS will be upgraded to a beta version on install, and can't be downgraded to stable again.

Comment: See Dmitri's answer above. This crash has been fixed in Xcode 11 Beta 2, I'm now able to open it in my Parallels VM.