# Xcode 11 beta and Mac OS Mojave: when I try to create a new project and/or open existing one it closes down with error

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-mojave, xcode11

I have just download Xcode 11 beta on my Mac. When I try to create a new project and/or open existing one it closes down with error

[image]

P.S.
This is from "Problem Report":

> Process:               Xcode [1445] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:               11.0 (14855.18) Build Info: 
>   IDEFrameworks-14855018000000000~13 Code Type:             X86-64
>   (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Gjk.gif) Responsible:           Xcode
>   [1445] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2019-06-11 13:55:52.981 +0500 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F203) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
>   6D358433-00BD-5BC6-9B1C-CED75E13E0B5
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       302231F5-ADEE-4E2B-B808-26494210C848
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 19000 seconds Time Since Wake:       2400
>   seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4 Termination Reason:
>   Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4 Terminating Process:   exc handler [1445]
>
> Application Specific Information: Sending newProject: to
>    from (null)
>   ProductBuildVersion: 11M336w Performing @selector(newProject:) from
>   sender (null) 0x0

P.P.S.
Also I tried on the OS Catalina - the same story. Cannot start a project.

Comment: Instead of some gif, why not post the error you get?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - Ok, I am going to update the question.

Comment: Are you using a non admin user?

Comment: No, it is admin user.

Comment: I also have the same problem too. It works perfectly on my iMac but on my MacBook Pro Xcode crashes and I get this error message :( I hope this problem will be fixed soon!

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513563/xcode-11-beta-crashes-when-starting-in-virtual-machine

Comment: You might want to check which version of tools you're using if you're running multiple versions of Xcode on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem too. I checked twitter for solutions but found out some people are also experiencing this. What's weird for me is that it works perfectly fine on my Mac mini but not on my MacBook

EDIT:

I'm not sure which Mac you guys have but I have a 2011 running the Mojave patcher and I found out the Xcode 11 requires Metal. My MacBook Pro obviously doesn't have metal and my Mini does so that's the only thing that makes sense to me. The people I saw on twitter having the same problem are also running the patcher so that's another reason why I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This crash should be fixed in Beta 2.

https://twitter.com/louisdhauwe/status/1135643154034483201?s=21